# Universal replacement for file_get_contents? (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, url, rss

I'm having a bit of a problem with reading an XML file (RSS feed). I'm using file_get_contents to read the data, which works fine locally on Xampp, but won't work on my server.

I don't want to have to edit my php.ini file, I'm after a out-of-the-box solution if there is one (I want the code to be as portable as possible).

I am currently doing...

```
    //  Load Correct Feed
    $feed_url = $this->selectFeed($instance);
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
```

I've had a look for solutions (ie. cURL) but can't find a way that will be supported universally.

Please could someone point me in the right direction (if it is even possible)?

Comment: You won't find a single way that is supported *universally* (i.e. every server configuration). As far as a single solution, `curl` (IMO) is the simplest, most widespread.

Comment: There is no a solution that will work everywhere

Comment: You would need to evaluate the response and act accordingly by providing fallbacks. That's the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at cURL. I though it wasn't that widespread but after a look, I look mistaken.

Comment: Apologies. Done. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```